# error E/Typeface SANS-LOC FILE NOT FOUND

Tags: android

I am getting error E/Typeface SANS-LOC FILE NOT FOUND for hello world simple android application in andriod studio 1.4

thanks in advance

Comment: If you are working on Android Studio make sure your asset folder is under main and not res ...

Comment: I don't have asset folder anywhere in my project

Answer (score 3):

This error is device specific, nothing to do with coding.
I faced the same problem while trying on HTC device which was automatically resolved when tried on OnePlus One.
I guess it has something to do with the graphics and memory, if your app contains high resolution resources such as images or videos, removing or decreasing the size might help.

Comment: I am using a HTC One Max for development, I simply cannot reproduce this on anything else, its good to know somebody encountered the same

Answer (score 0):

@KirtiKarki you have to add SANS-LOC font in your assets folder in your project